# How do I split a 13 person team

Tags: scrum, agile, team-management, project-team

I am a scrum master/agile coach and the team I have been assigned to is too big, 13 people!

I have complete authority to change this however I want to formulate a good plan to do this.

Can anyone suggest how I initiate this process. So not where the split happens but how to approach it.

My rough plan was just to have 1-on-1’s with everyone and see if there is a common thread. Theming a retro around it seems like I am pushing the concept on them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whatever you do don't split them into two equal sized teams - that would be awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Theming a retro around it seems like I am pushing the concept on them.

Why do you believe that?  How is it different from the "1-on-1’s" approach?  What advice do the values contained in the [Manifesto for Agile Software Development](http://agilemanifesto.org/) give you?  Can you apply the values and rules in [The Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) to this situation?

- Self-organizing teams.
- Transparency.
- **People and interactions** over processes and tools.

Answer (score 5):

Self-Organized teams start with self-organization.

The normal advice I give to clients is to create a User Story for what is a "good team" with clear acceptance.

Then you get everyone in a room. You show them to user story, tell them how many teams should exist and then let them self-organize into teams. Usually you will go through 2-3 iterations of this before you have your final set.

As Simon Sinek says, "Hire for attitude, you can teach skill." For teams for fit first. Skills will improve faster with a good team.